# Apache server cannot find local file

Tags: apache, flask

I am hosting a flask application with Apache Server. The app runs fine, but as soon as I enter a route which access a local config.json file, it fails. The error logs look like this :

```
[Mon Nov 18 17:07:30.173596 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 7752:tid 1096] [client 127.0.0.1:49776]     conf = open('\\config.json', "r")\r
[Mon Nov 18 17:07:30.173596 2019] [wsgi:error] [pid 7752:tid 1096] [client 127.0.0.1:49776] FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '\\\\config.json'
```

I have tried entering the file name as 'config.json' as well, I still get a similar file not found error.

I was going through some documentation on the httpd.conf file and here is how my directory tag is setup

```
<Directory />
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks Includes ExecCGI
    AllowOverride All
    Require all granted    
</Directory>
```

Here is how my Flask code looks like :

```
@app.route('/new')
def new():
    conf = open('\config.json', "r")
    data = json.loads(conf.read())   
    db_conf = data['db_connection']
    host = db_conf['host']    
    DB = db_conf['DB']
    return "Host : {}, DB : {}".format(DB, host)
```

I have given all permissions to the file and folder in the securities section.

Is there any other setting which needs to be changed so that the server can see the file. When I run the server through cmd, it works without issues.

Comment: In your position, I'd convince myself of what the current directory was by writing a test route that returned `os.getcwd()`.

Comment: Yes, that was the issue @DaveW.Smith! The cwd was the folder of my Apache24 download. But that brings me to a follow up question. If my app is at another location, then to refer to each file, do I need to give the entire file path. Is there a way I can specify relative path in my web app?